# TensorFlow Dataset - how to play / convert WAV-File (int64)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio

i want to test the following Dataset: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/speech_commands

when i load & play the audio i just get ?random? noise.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import IPython.display as ipd


ds, ds_info = tfds.load('speech_commands', shuffle_files=False, with_info=True)
ds_info
```

```json
tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
    name='speech_commands',
    full_name='speech_commands/0.0.2',
    description="""
    An audio dataset of spoken words designed to help train and evaluate keyword
    spotting systems. Its primary goal is to provide a way to build and test small
    models that detect when a single word is spoken, from a set of ten target words,
    with as few false positives as possible from background noise or unrelated
    speech. Note that in the train and validation set, the label "unknown" is much
    more prevalent than the labels of the target words or background noise.
    One difference from the release version is the handling of silent segments.
    While in the test set the silence segments are regular 1 second files, in the
    training they are provided as long segments under "background_noise" folder.
    Here we split these background noise into 1 second clips, and also keep one of
    the files for the validation set.
    """,
    homepage='https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03209',
    data_path='C:\\Users\\abc\\tensorflow_datasets\\speech_commands\\0.0.2',
    download_size=2.37 GiB,
    dataset_size=9.07 GiB,
    features=FeaturesDict({
        'audio': Audio(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64),
        'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=12),
    }),
    supervised_keys=('audio', 'label'),
    splits={
        'test': <SplitInfo num_examples=4890, num_shards=4>,
        'train': <SplitInfo num_examples=106497, num_shards=128>,
        'validation': <SplitInfo num_examples=121, num_shards=1>,
    },
    citation="""@article{speechcommandsv2,
       author = {{Warden}, P.},
        title = "{Speech Commands: A Dataset for Limited-Vocabulary Speech Recognition}",
      journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
      archivePrefix = "arXiv",
      eprint = {1804.03209},
      primaryClass = "cs.CL",
      keywords = {Computer Science - Computation and Language, Computer Science - Human-Computer Interaction},
        year = 2018,
        month = apr,
        url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03209},
    }""",
)
```

The Audio files are Arrays of Type `int64` with a Samplerate of 16000. I couldnt find any information on how to play the Files within this Dataset. From other Datasets i was able to play the WAV-Sounds. One of the difference is, that other DS used float arrays and this DS uses int array. Maybe im missing a conversation step?

```py
ds_list = list(ds['validation'])

idx = -1
audio, label = ds_list[idx]['audio'], ds_list[idx]['label']
ipd.Audio(audio, rate=16_000)
```

I obviously tried multiple Indeces within the Dataset but i always just get noise. One Audio-Entry looks something like this:
`tf.Tensor([ -112  1285 -2002 ...  -140  1000  -595], shape=(16000,), dtype=int64)`

Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the source code, on the description page [1], it is stated that:

> Its primary goal is to provide a way to build and test small
> models that detect when a single word is spoken, from a set of ten target words,
> with as few false positives as possible from background noise or unrelated
> speech.

At first, I was able to play noisy wavfile as you have shown. Then, I modify my codes based on [2] to produce cleaner voice.

I use the following code to convert tensor to wav format.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# load speech commands dataset
ds = tfds.load('speech_commands', split=['train', 'validation', 'test'],
           shuffle_files=True)

# convert from tfds format to list
ds_train = list(ds[0])
ds_val = list(ds[1])

# convert from tensor int64 to numpy float32
sc1 = ds_list[0]['audio'].numpy().astype(np.float32)/np.iinfo(np.int16).max()
sv1 = ds_list[1]['audio'].numpy().astype(np.float32)/np.iinfo(np.int16).max()

# save as wav
wavfile('sc_train_1.wav', 16000, sc1)
wavfile('sc_train_1.wav', 16000, sv1)
```

The trick is to convert int64 to float32 and divide by max value of np.int16: `.astype(np.float32)/np.iinfo(np.int16).max()`.

Now, I can hear a cleaner voice than previously int64 format.

[1]https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets/audio/speech_commands.py
[2] https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/master/non_semantic_speech_benchmark/train_and_eval_sklearn_small_tfds_dataset.ipynb